# use a callback function before a .done() function in ajax call promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is schematically what I am trying to achieve :

```
function loadLotsofSomething() {
    for (var i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        results.push(loadOneSomething(i))
    }

    $.when.apply(this,results).done(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            //get doSomehting(data) instead of data here
        }
    }   
}

function loadOneSomething(i) {
    return $.ajax({
        async : true,
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            return doSomething(data);
        }
    });
}

function doSomething (x) {
    return x;
}
```

I would want the `success` function to execute before the `done` function because It's simpler to modify the data I get from the ajax call before looping through all the calls.

In my case, no matter what I put into the `success` function, I always get the raw data in the `done` function.

Any help welcome !

Comment: Where is your `results` variable defined?

Comment: yes, the success function **is** executing before the `$.when...done` function - your problem is lack of understanding of success function, returning something there does nothing

Comment: @empiric it's just a pseudo-code, not the real deal

Comment: @JaromandaX unhelpful comment. Please explain how the success function works then.

Comment: @Chapo - I would've gone further into it, except the answer below was posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use *chaining* (as is often the case with promises). Don't use `success` at all; instead, use `then` and return its result:

```
function loadOneSomething(i) {
    return $.ajax({
        async : true,
        url: url
    }).then(function(data){
        return doSomething(data);
    });
}
```

That way, the promise returned by `loadOneSomething` is the one from `then`, not the one from `$.ajax`, and its resolution value is what you return from `then`.

More: [The jqXHR entry in `$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR), [`deferred.then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/).